# HTML scraping using lxml and requests gives a unicode error

Tags: python, html, unicode, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to use HTML scraper like the one provided [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/). It works fine for the example they provided. However, when I try using it with my [webpage](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/gene/analysis?ln=PTEN&ln1=PTEN&start=130&end=140&coords=bp%3AAA&sn=&ss=&hn=&sh=&id=15#), I receive this error - `Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

I've tried googling but couldn't find a solution. I'd truly appreciate any help. I'd like to know if there's a way to copy it as HTML using Python.

Edit:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic/gene/analysis?ln=PTEN&ln1=PTEN&start=130&end=140&coords=bp%3AAA&sn=&ss=&hn=&sh=&id=15#')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce your scraper to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the error and copy-paste that short program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ I've added the code and the error is still the same: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Short answer: use `page.content`, not `page.text`.

From http://lxml.de/parsing.html#python-unicode-strings :

> > the parsers in lxml.etree can handle unicode strings straight away ... This requires, however, that unicode strings do not specify a conflicting encoding themselves and thus lie about their real encoding

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content :

> > Requests will automatically decode content from the server [as `r.text`]. ... You can also access the response body as bytes [as `r.content`].

So you see, both `requests.text` and `lxml.etree` want to decode the utf-8 to unicode. But if we let `requests.text` do the decoding, then the encoding statement inside the xml file becomes a lie.

So, let's have `requests.content` do no decoding. That way `lxml` will receive a consistently undecoded file.