# parsing XML from a string into an element

Tags: python, xml, unicode, elementtree

I have had some troubles to parse a XML from a string directly into an Element.
I a have an xml file that I have transform into a string:

```
resp = requests.post(request_url, request_string,   proxies=urllib.getproxies(), stream=True)
```

And as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25023776/1551810, I used the contenet instead of the text:

```
response_tree = ET.fromstring(resp.content)
```

I apparently have a Syntax erro in the XML file :

```
XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xB0 0x20 0x4E 0x6F, line 12, column 35
```

I tried this to encode the content but to no avail:

```
ET.fromstring(resp.content.encode('utf8'))
```

I have the same XMLSYntaxError than before.
Can anyone help me? 
I already have spent two hours on this.

Comment: The comment says that it is *not* utf-8, so you need to figure out in what encoding the data actually is, and then either transcode (decode from encoding, then encode into utf-8), or specify a proper xml-header

Comment: Thanks, for you quick answer,
The data is a string and I decoded it. I now have a UnicodeDecodeError. 
Can you please develop your idea?

Comment: Very similar to this PHP problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-lo; as @deets suggested, you need to get your encoding in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a great library that helped me to solve the problem: cchardet(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/0.3.5)
And I followed @deets advice.

```
import cchardet
charac_coding_desired = 'UTF-8'
encoding = cchardet.detect(resp.content)['encoding']
if charac_coding_desired != encoding:
    strg= resp.content.decode(encoding, resp.content).encode(charac_coding_desired)
```

Now I can parse brutally the string:

```
ET.fromstring(strg)
```

Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Good work solving the problem and posting back your results. After a short delay you should now be able to mark your own answer as solved. Please do this and you will help other people who are having the same problem.